# Как удалить нужный элемент с массива?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть карточки с data атрибутом где лежат их id и по клику на карточку id попадает в массив ( что-то тип [1, 22, 9]), также есть кнопки для удаления карточки с таким же id, как найти и удалить нужный элемент в массиве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для удаления вначале нужно найти индекс нужной тебе карточки с помощью `indexOf()`, к примеру так:

```
var removeId = this.items.indexOf(id);
```

А потом сделать `splice()` от этого индекса длинной 1:

```
this.items.splice(removeId, 1);
```

Возможно не лучший вариант, но рабочий